# Lightning component to update a field on the record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, javascript-controller, ownership

I am trying to replace the Javascript button to Take Ownership on the Case to a lightning component like below

Controller

```
({ 
  recordLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    var caseRecord = component.get("v.record"),
      recordData = component.find("recordData");
      var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
      caseRecord.OwnerId = userId ;

    if(!component.get("v.complete")) { // Avoid infinite loop
      component.set("v.complete", true);
      component.set("v.record", caseRecord);
      recordData.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
        if(result.state === "SUCCESS" || result.state === "DRAFT") {
          $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
          $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        } 
      }));
  }
  }})
```

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' }" />
  <aura:attribute name="complete" type="Boolean" default="false" />
  <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    fields="['CaseNumber','OwnerId','OwnerFullName']"
                    targetFields="{!v.record}"
                    aura:id="recordData"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```

But this throws error when I click on the quick action like

[image]

Can anyone please guide as what I am missing here.

Comment: Why not simply use a Quick Action and do this with no code at all?

Comment: Have you placed some console logs to check your userId/ownerId is actually populated? From the error message it says it’s null.